# Is it possible to implement an event-driven architecture using Redis Streams?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, rabbitmq, redis-streams

In my .NET application,
I'm utilizing Redis Stream as a message broker and aiming to implement an event-driven architecture with Redis Streams.

I'm looking for functionality similar to RabbitMQ, where a method like Received on the EventingBasicConsumer triggers an event (ConsumerReceive) when a new message is received on the queue.

I need a corresponding mechanism for Redis Streams to handle new message events efficiently.

```
// when message received on queue then it will trigger ConsumerReceive event
        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += ConsumerReceive;
```